# How to retrieve saved password of VPN on Windows 10?

Tags: vpn, passwords, password-recovery

I have a saved VPN on Windows 10 and I've forgotten its password. I need the password to log in to the site that provides my VPN (my university site, it doesn't have any "forgot" option).

Windows 10 lets me see all about my VPN except the password! [image: Picture]

and even in its editing

[image: picture]

How can I retrieve my VPN password?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[NirSoft Dialuppass](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dialupass.html) recovery tool can do that for you.

Please note that some anit-virus software might alert you and quarantine/remove this tool because they categorize it as a suspicious malware (for example AVG considers it as safe, but Bitdefender completely removes it). You have to make a decision to allow elevated access to your computer for this tool or not.

If you're concerned about your privacy then you should avoid using password recovery tools and contact the VPN administrator requesting for a new password.

Comment: thanks for introducing this tool! amazing usage for me!

Comment: Whenever I try to unzip this file on Windows 11 it keeps getting quarantined (deleted).  How do I allow it?

Answer (score 2):

Download from here to view https://www.nirsoft.net/toolsdownload/dialupass.zip Zip File Password: nsdlps3861@

Comment: Welcome to superuser! :) Note that the same tool has already been recommended in the accepted answer.